# Select with SQL the oldest payment associated to a list of persons

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Having troubles with a SQL query on an Oracle database (11G I think).

I need to make a query on two tables. The first one contains identifiers of persons. The second one contains payments (you can consider it as salaries), each record associated to the person with a foreign key.

What I need to do is retrieve, for a known list of persons (let's say identifiers 1, 2, 5 and 10), the oldest payment (based on the payment date).

What I made first is this :

```
select id_person, MIN(payment_date) 
from payment where id_person in (1, 2, 5, 10)
group by id_person;
```

This retrieves something like :

```
1   19940623
2   20100429
5   20100204
10  20100111
```

Now, how do I get, for each person, the complete record of the ´payment´ table which correspond to the oldest payment ?

I cannot figure out a way of doing this...

The answer must be in a single SQL query (I cannot make a call for each person, which would be very easy to do...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
select *
from (
   select id_person, 
          payment_date,
          row_number() over (partition by id_person order by payment_date) as rn
   from payment
   where id_person ind (1,2,5,10)
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This one does exactly what I need to do. I do not see real performance increase compared to the two other solutions, but less data are transferred from the database to the Java application server. I'll keep this one ! Thanks !

Comment: @Wis: As the inner query already reduces the number of rows substantially there isn't a big difference between a self-join and this solution. But if you do this for all rows then I'd expect the solution with the windowing function to perform better (because only a single table scan will be needed).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 select * from payment p
 where id_person in (1, 2, 5, 10)
    And payment_date =
       (Select Min(payment_date)
        From payment
        Where id_person = p.id_person)
```

based on your comment:  The solution is easy if the payment table has a key (a primary key or unique index).  If so, say the key is on column paymentId, then..

```
 select * from payment p
 where id_person in (1, 2, 5, 10)
    And paymentId =
       (Selcet paymentId From payment p2
        Where id_person = p.id_person
           And payment_date =
             (Select Min(payment_date)
              From payment
              Where id_person = p.id_person))
```

Comment: This is almost working. I discovered that there can be several payments for the same date and the same person. Consequently, your query can return several payments, all located to the oldest date. Is it possible to get only one record ? I dont care which of the oldest payments as the date is the only thing I really need to retrieve (the complete record needs however to be returned due to an ORM usage).

Comment: Yes, in tat case, if the table has a PK, you can use it to identify a single record.  see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM Payment INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_person, MIN(payment_date) 
    FROM payment p 
    WHERE id_person IN (1, 2, 5, 10)
    GROUP BY id_person;
    )
    ON Payment.id_person = p.idPerson AND Payment.payment_date = p.payment_date
```

Comment: Does exactly the same than Charles' proposal. However, yours run with half the performance (tests performed on a reduced set, maybe not very accurate). I'll stick to Charles' one.

Comment: Never claimed that it was faster. It's another option and I tried to stay closer to your query. Not really surprised though, go for the best performance. I don't have Oracle to look at the execution plan